# Linux Bash script to ping multiple hosts simultaneously

Tags: linux, multithreading, bash, scripting, background-process

I have a text file with list of 500 server names.  I need to ping all of them simultaneously instead of one by one in a loop, and put the pingable ones in one file and unpingable ones in another file.

Can I run each ping in background or spawn a new process for each ping? What is the quickest and most efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you need to send 500 at once? I don't think that this can be done unless you have 500/(ave number of cores per processor) processors... If you just want the speed up, why not ping 8 at once and iterate?

Comment: Do you care about the output or result of the pings? How much will you ping each host? And remember that creating 500 processes takes time, maybe you could split it up into fewer processes each doing sequential pings?

Answer (score 4):

You can control the parallelism by using `xargs`:

```
cat file-of-ips | xargs -n 1 -I ^ -P 50 ping ^
```

Here we're keeping at most 50 pings going at a time.  The ip itself is inserted at the `^`; you can put arguments before and after.